# Automatically "git add" all files created under a specific folder

Tags: git

In git, is there a way to automatically "git add" all files created or placed under a specific folder?

Comment: Yes, you can use `git add path/to/folder/*.java`, for example, to add all Java files under that specific path.

Comment: The default behaviour of get add on a folder is to add all files under it (recursively). You need no more than `git add path/to/folder`.

Comment: Ex. in laravel, I frequently create files under app/Event, database/Migrations and database/Seeds/ , and all are essential to my project, everytime I create files under those folder i always use git add, I want it to be automatic.

Comment: Maybe you can add a scheduler which runs every 10 seconds or something and does git add of particular directory you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux/Unix systems (possibly in `git-bash` too) you could achieve this by using:

```
watch -n5 git add /path/to/folder
```

Which will result in repeating the git add command every 5 seconds.

However `watch` is a common linux/unix command and it has nothing to do with `git` meaning that if I were to answer your question **literally** you can't do this **in `git`** per se.

Comment: will try this, tnx @Mihai

Answer (score 0):

`git add -A -- <folder_path>` can do the 'add' part. But the 'automatically' part is unknown to me.

Comment: Ex. in laravel, I frequently create files under app/Event, database/Migrations and database/Seeds/ , and all are essential to my project, everytime I create files under those folder i always use git add, I want it to be automatic.